# JBoss standalone.conf VS standalone.conf.bat

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

I'm currently checking up on our **JBoss AS7.1** server configuration and I discovered these two previously-configured files in our `jboss/standalone/bin` directory:

- standalone.conf
- standalone.conf.bat

Now I'm interested in tweaking our `JAVA_OPTS` and both the config files have a location where the parameters are set. From a quick Google search I think `standalone.conf.bat` is the usual file for setting these. But I'm not sure what the standalone.conf file is doing here. Do I only need to modify `standalone.conf.bat` or is there any configuration ordering I should take note of when modifying these two files?

**Update:**

The relevant JBoss documentation that answers this can be found here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JVM+settings

Comment: I also have the original `standalone.bat` file in my bin directory, from what I gathered in Jboss forums, the the bat file takes its configuration parameters from `standalone.conf.bat`

Comment: The `bat` file is for Windows environments, the non-bat file is for *Nix. If you look through the startup scripts you will notice that `standalone.bat` will 'include' standalone.conf.bat when run, and `standalone.sh` will include `standalone.conf`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are running this on Windows then you only really need to worry about modifying the `standalone.conf.bat` file. The other file (`standalone.conf`) is only used by *Nix environments.